# Existence of a positively homogeneous function of degree $k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

> For every $k \in \mathbb R$ show that there exists a function $f: \mathbb R^m - \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ of class $C^{\infty}$, positively homogeneous of degree $k$, that is, $f(tx) = t^k f(x)$ , for every $x \in \mathbb R^m - \{0\}$, with $t > 0$, such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ and $f$ is not a polynomial.

**Attempt:** I have tried to work with $$f(x) = \frac{1}{k\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{x_j^k}}$$

Then $f(tx) = t^k f(x)$. But I have failed to show that $f(x) > 0$. From $$f(tx) - f(x) = f'(x) \cdot (t-1)x + \rho(x) (t-1) |x|\tag{*}$$

and $$f'(x) \cdot x = \frac{f(x)}{k} $$

I took $t \to 1^+$ and got $k^2 = 1$.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Think of the unit sphere. (For the thing you started with, if $k$ is not an integer, what is $x_j^k$ for $x_j < 0$? Try using $\lvert x_j\rvert^k$ instead. But that still runs into problems when some coordinate is $0$ and $k < 0$.)

Comment: Thanks for you time. What about $f(x) = \displaystyle \max_{1\leq j \leq m} |x_j|^k$?

Comment: That should probably be $\bigl(\max\limits_{1 \leq j \leq m} \lvert x_j\rvert\bigr)^k$ to avoid the problem of $0^{-\pi}$ etc. That has the problem of not being $C^{\infty}$, otherwise it works.

Comment: I see. I've been thinking quite a while about this. But every example I can think of fails on either one of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$ is any norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function that is positively homogeneous of degree $k$, then for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}$ we have

$$f(x) = f\biggl(\lVert x\rVert\cdot \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\biggr) = \lVert x\rVert^k \cdot f\biggl(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\biggr),$$

so $f$ is determined by its values on the unit sphere $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \lVert x\rVert = 1\}$. And any function $g \colon S \to \mathbb{R}$ uniquely determines a positively homogeneous function $f$ of degree $k$ by setting

$$f(x) = \lVert x\rVert^k\cdot g\biggl(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\biggr).\tag{$\ast$}$$

$f$ will be strictly positive if and only if $g$ is strictly positive. And $f$ will be continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous.

We want a $C^{\infty}$ function, and to get that conveniently, we should focus on a smooth norm, because then the unit sphere of that norm is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}$. Usually, unless specified otherwise, one endows $\mathbb{R}^m$ with the Euclidean norm, which is smooth. But one could also choose many other smooth norms, a rather prominent family is the family of $\ell^p$-norms $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_p$ where $1 < p < \infty$ (the Euclidean norm is the case $p = 2$; the norms $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty}$ are not smooth for $m > 1$).

Anyway, if we use a smooth norm, then the positively homogeneous $f$ induced by $g$ will be smooth if and only if $g$ is smooth.

So, take the Euclidean norm, take any smooth function $g \colon S \to (0,\infty)$, and $f$ defined by $(\ast)$ will be a smooth function, positively homogeneous of degree $k$, and strictly positive. If $k \notin \mathbb{N}$, then $f$ cannot be a polynomial, since it has the wrong growth behaviour. For even $k \in \mathbb{N}$, some choices of $g$ will yield polynomials, but not all. If you choose $g$ in such a way that there is a point $p \in S$ with $g(-p) \neq g(p)$, then $f$ will not be a polynomial.